# Star Formation in the future

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, star-formation, observable-universe

From what I understand stars form in dense clouds of hydrogen and helium molecules. Only so much hydrogen and helium were "created" from the Big Bang or rather formed if you may.

Is it conceivably possible for the universe to not have any more hydrogen and helium to condense into a molecular cloud and form new stars? Meaning will star formation cease at some point in the far far far away future.